# Problems with handling exceptions from async method with tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I hope you can help me with that problem.

I have a method that does specific actions, for example, I am sending a HttpWebRequest. There I can get a **WebException**, so I put it in a Try-Catch-block to rethrow exceptions for more specific exception messages.

Like that: (This is in a method called **doWebRequest**)

```
try 
{
   // HttpWebRequest here
}

catch (WebException ex)
{
  throw new WebException(String.Format("My special additional message {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Well, so this works, when I call this function normally.
But now I want an async way to do this. What I made to call this method in an async method:

```
public void DoRequestAsync() 
{
   Task internalRequest = new Task(doWebRequest);
   internalRequest.ContinueWith(InternalUpdateSearchExceptionHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
   internalRequest.Start();
}
```

So this makes a new task and then calls the method **doWebRequest** async.
To handle errors now, because I know it is different on async, I made this handler, which you can also see in **internalRequest.ContinueWith**. Looks like that:

```
private void InternalUpdateSearchExceptionHandler(Task task)
{
  var ex = task.Exception;
  if (ex.InnerException is WebException)
  {
     if ((ex.InnerException as WebException).Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
     {
        throw new WebException(ex.InnerException.Message);
     }

     else
     {
        throw new Exception("There was no response from the server.");
     }
  }
}
```

But this is not executing any exceptions. I don't know why.
At first I thought, this is because it cannot take the InnerException as a WebException, or would that work? If not, please tell me what to do here. But even when I throw an exception without any queries here, it did not throw any exceptions while debugging. Why is that?

Help is appreciated. When something is not clear, ask me. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Your continuation is throwing an exception, but when that continuation throws an exception all that happens is the `Task` that represents that continuation is marked as Faulted with the given exception as its Exception.  You currently are ignoring the task created by calling `ContinueWith`, so there is nothing to observe this exception.

`DoRequestAsync` likely shouldn't be `void`; rather it should return a `Task`, specifically the one created by calling `ContinueWith`, so that whoever calls this method can observe any exceptions thrown.

Also note that you could do this much more simply using `async`:

```
public async Task DoRequestAsync() 
{
    try 
    {
        var content = await new WebClient()
            .DownloadStringTaskAsync("address");
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
      throw new WebException(String.Format("My special additional message {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am on .NET 4.0, so async-await is not the right solution for me ;)
So, thanks for the explanation.
If I would make doRequestAsync a Task, what would the "return" look like in my case?

Comment: @Trade As I said, you'd simply return the task created by `ContinueWith`.

Comment: So I have now: return internalRequest.ContinueWith(InternalUpdateSearchExceptionHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

But is this all? I am a bit confused at the moment.
I tested this, but there were no exceptions coming up.

Comment: @Trade Presumably whatever is calling *that* method is just ignoring the `Task` that it returns, instead of inspecting it and doing something if it is faulted.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at it again tomorrow and then see what I will do. Thanks!

Comment: @Trade: You can use `async` on .NET 4.0 if you install `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Is this then qvailabke only locally in my VS, or also in other one's, because I am writing a lib.

Comment: @Trade: in any. If you distribute your lib in a NuGet package, then you can just pull in `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` as a dependency.

Comment: Well ok, but without NuGet thi would also work on other PCs then?